# MsiGetProductInfo returning ERROR_UNKNOWN_PRODUCT for an installed product

Tags: c#, windows, registry, windows-installer

I am trying to programmatically query for information from the installer project.  This information is defined in the installer and I don't want to duplicate it in code.  I need to get the Publisher installer property (and a few others), but can't seem to get things to work.

I am querying using:

```
[DllImport("msi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern Int32 MsiGetProductInfo(
    string product, 
    string property, 
    [Out] StringBuilder valueBuf, 
    ref Int32 len);
```

...

```
int length = 512;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
var result = MsiGetProductInfo(
    "{censored}", 
    "Publisher", 
    builder, 
    ref length);
```

Using RegEdit, I can see an uninstallable product:

> {censored}_is1

And this is my application with a "Publisher" key that is what I expect.  I am not sure why the "_is1" suffix is there.  The installer was made using Inno Setup, maybe that is related.  I have tried adding this suffix on the product code in the call to MsiGetProductInfo but it had no effect.

The call returns 1605 which is ERROR_UNKNOWN_PRODUCT.

How do I properly query for the publisher of this product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSI API is only useful for MSI-based installations. Inno Setup does not create MSI packages so you can't use the MSI API to query about Inno Setup installations.

Comment: I guess it is time to add registry keys then.  Thanks Bob, I needed that.